# Добавление переменной в SQL через JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Подключаюсь к базе c помощью jdbc. Хотел бы создать в SQL запросе переменную, которую потом можно было бы подставлять  в основную логику программы на Java.
Как это можно реализовать.

Comment: *Хотел бы создать в SQL запросе переменную, которую потом можно было бы подставлять в основную логику программы на Java.* Если Вы имеете в виду, что выполнение SQL-запроса на MySQL-сервере должно создать на клиентской рабочей станции переменную, доступную в Вашей Java-программе - так это невозможно. А если что-то иное - то, вероятно, неплохо бы получше продумать формулировку вопроса...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так устанавливайте соединение:

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("url", "username", "password");
```

И потом записывайте в таблицу ваши данные:

```
// Вам понадобится сам sql запрос
String sql = "INSERT INTO exemple (id, val) VALUES (DEFAULT, (?))"

//Создаете PreparedStatement что-бы не забыть закрыть лучше открывать в try-with-resources
try (final PreparedStatement statement =
             //сюда передаете sql запрос:
             connection.prepareStatement(sql)) {

    //Тут у вас задаются значения для (?).
    //Вместо (?) подставляете значение ("test"). Индексация параметров(wildcard) - (?) начинается от 1.
    statement.setString(1, "test");

    //Выполняете сам запрос в базу.
    statement.executeUpdate();

} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Это сработает если ваша таблица выглядит на пример так:

```
CREATE TABLE exemple (
    id SERIAL,
    val TEXT,
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Вам нужно использовать `PreparedStatement`. Вот пример из [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html)

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement("UPDATE EMPLOYEES
                                                SET SALARY = ? WHERE ID = ?");
pstmt.setBigDecimal(1, 153833.00)
pstmt.setInt(2, 110592)
```